# find VCC, GND and IN in relay

Tags: relay

I`m new to electronic stuff, I was reading an [artice](http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-AC-light-using-Arduino-with-relay-modu/) on how control AC light using arduino, In part of solution there is a relay module which has a VCC and GND and IN and COM and NO and NC, but I don`t have that module instead, I have a relay like this:[image]

can you please help me to find VCC, GND and IN in my relay? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a part number?

Comment: That module you saw probably has at the very least a transistor included to actually drive the relay. All you have there is a base relay.

Comment: @I.Wolfe hrs4h-s-dc5v

Comment: @brhans so you mean I can\`t create that circuit in the link?

Comment: I have googled with first result as a part's datasheet with exact pinout. What is the problem?

Comment: @EugeneSh.there is six pinout in that tutorial, but there is five pinout on my relay

Comment: COM, NO and NC are the relay contacts (common, normally open, and normally closed).  The two remaining terminals are the relay coil.  The relay module you mention apparently has some additional circuitry (a transistor or opto-coupler, probably) to drive the relay coil.

Comment: @PeterBennett so I don\`t need to connect anything to pin 7 in the link above?

Comment: @Yashar: That instructable is using a program in the Arduino to control the relay by setting the Arduino's pin 7 high or low.  If you don't have an Arduino, you obviously don't have an Arduino pin 7 to drive the relay.  You should not attempt to drive the relay directly from a microcontroller output pin, as they can't provide enough current - you would use a micro output pin to control a transistor, which in turn would drive the relay.

Comment: @Yashar - This data sheet http://www.comsel.it/risorse/0013901.pdf shows 5 pins. Please provide a link to the data sheet which shows 6.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I don\`t have a part number for relay with 6 pins, They are using it in tutorial that I have posted its link above. Mine has 5 pins

Comment: @PeterBennett I have an arduino, but in the code he controls the light with pin 7, the pin which I don\`t know what should I connect to

Comment: I find the solution, There is no need to connect GND to arduino, Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relay has 5 pins, which are almost certainly the two connections to the coil, and the common (COM), normally-open (NO), and normally-closed (NC) connections of the switch.

To find out which is which, use a ohmmeter.  There will be some finite resistance between the two coil leads, probably a few 10s of Ohms, maybe up to 100 or two Ohms.  The resistance between each of these pins and any of the other three will be infinite.  The COM and NC pins will be shorted together (well under 1 Ohm).  The NO pin will have infinite reistance to all other pins.  Until you activate the relay, you won't be able to tell the differnence between the COM and NC pins.

Guessing from the layout of the pins shown in your picture, the coil pins are the two at right.  This guess is based on the fact that there are two of them grouped separately from the others.  Relays are sometimes used for their electrical isolation between their input (the coil) and their output (the switch contacts).  As such, there is often a larger physical distance between these two sets of pins.

Flip the relay over and look at what is printed on the top.  This will often tell you the voltage or current the coil requires to activate the switch, and what the switch is rated for.

You aren't going to be able to drive this relay directly from the digital output of a microcontroller.  A simple low side NPN switch is usually the easiest way to control a relay from a digital output.  There are many questions here already on that topic, so no need to repeat the details in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your relay's datasheet:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ouch.

What you have in your picture is a plain old relay.  Your Arduino most likely can't drive that relay directly.

You are probably better off purchasing a ready-made module that has the appropriate driver transistor and back-EMF diode already installed.

You *CAN* do it yourself but I'm worried about you not being able to work with AC Mains power safely.  If you don't have somebody local to you to help you through this project, you are better off with the pre-manufactured module.

Comment: I find the solution for my situation with that old relay, but I think relay you mentioned is safer because of GND pin

Answer (score 0):

You have made an understandable mistake. The relays in the link you provided do not have a Vcc connection, and they have only 5 pins. The relay MODULE (the complete PC board with relay intstalled) does use 6 pins, and does use Vcc. The MODULE has, in addition to the two relays, two ICs (8 pins each). These ICs are driver chips, and they are what actually drive the relays. The VCC input provides power for the drivers and the relay coils.

As a matter of fact, if you look at the Arduino connection block, you'll see that it has VCC, GND, and 2 inputs, 1 for each relay. So the module as a whole has 10 pins.

And I have no idea why your module can run without connecting ground. It may be that you are connecting it to the power supply ground that also connects to the Arduino, but in that case you are, in fact, electrically connecting it to the Arduino.